# how to get updated data automatically after 10 sec using setinterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

i am trying to get data after each 10 seconds, i did it perfectly but the problem is my DOM renders first time i get data but as 10 seconds passed it did'nt update data and shows an error related to data...

[here's the DOM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Sqq.png)

CODE
**App.js**

```
import { Appbar } from './components/pageOne/Appbar'
import { Cards } from './components/pageOne/Cards'
import { fetchData } from './components/FetchDataFromApi'



function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  const a = useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => setData(), 10000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  })

  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetchData();
      setData(fetchedData)
    })()
    // let interval = setInterval(() => setData(), 10000)
    // return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [a])


  return (
    <>
    <Appbar />
    <Cards data = {data} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

````
const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api'

export const fetchData = async (country) => {
    let changeableUrl = url
    
    if (country) {
    changeableUrl = `${url}/countries/${country}`
  }

  try {
      const {data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths}} = await axios.get(changeableUrl)

      return { confirmed, 
               recovered,
               deaths
            }
  }
      catch 
      (error) {
          return error
      }
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the data to `undefined` after 10 seconds -

```
let interval = setInterval(() => setData(), 10000)
```

You need to go and fetch the data again -

```
let interval = setInterval(async () => {
    const fetchedData = await fetchData();
    setData(fetchedData)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: this delay get request or data rendering initially for 10 seconds as page refresh , but after 10 seconds data is not refreshing still,

Comment: Are you sure it's not refreshing? Does the data actually change every 10 seconds? If not, it would render the same content as the previous 10 seconds ago. Perhaps I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve - could you put up a CodeSandbox to help?

Comment: here is the link. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-easley-fn4g5?file=/src/Cards.js)

Comment: The code I've put above is correct - [if you put a `console.log` in your `setInterval` you can see it refreshing](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bird-ukj0j?file=/src/App.js). The reason it doesn't change the counters is because the values haven't changed between refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

1. destructing in fetchData function is not correct.

```
    export const fetchData = async (country) => {
      let changeableUrl = url
      
      if (country) {
        changeableUrl = `${url}/countries/${country}`
      }

    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
        const { confirmed, recovered, deaths } = resp.data;
    
        return { confirmed, 
                 recovered,
                 deaths
              }
    }
        catch 
        (error) {
            return error
        }
    }
```

2. useEffect is not used correctly.  Here is the correction.

```
    import { Appbar } from "./components/pageOne/Appbar";
    import { Cards } from "./components/pageOne/Cards";
    import { fetchData } from "./components/FetchDataFromApi";
    
    function App() {
      const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(async () => {
          const newData = await fetchData();
          setData(newData);
        }, 10000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          <Appbar />
          <Cards data={data} />
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

You can also checkout this sample code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lewin-vl9g0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it is not working, no data no card components render on DOM when i use this logic

Comment: plz check now..made some changes with respect to axios and also included sample code link

Comment: [codeSandBox] (https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-easley-fn4g5?file=/src/Cards.js)

Comment: its working.. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hoover-qyqde)